# How to compile Clang on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, clang

I have been trying to find a way to get Clang working on Windows but am having trouble. I get Clang to compile successfully, but when I try to compile a program I have a bunch of errors in the standard headers.

I am aware of [rubenvb's excellent prebuilt versions of clang](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/), but I want to compile it for myself. I also was listening to the GoingNative talks about clang which said that it didn't have very good Windows support yet. How can I get clang working on Windows?

Comment: PreBuilt clang for windows : http://sourceforge.net/projects/clangonwin/

Comment: For anybody looking, I found [these](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/How-to-build-LLVM,-libclang,-and-liblld-from-source) instructions straight forward. There are only 4 steps there.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I used the following method to compile clang for C++ on Windows 7 and it has been validated by Mysticial and others:

1. Download and install [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download) (make sure you install the C++ compiler) and put the bin folder in your PATH (I have MinGW 4.6.1 and tested successfully on another computer with 4.6.2)
2. Make sure you have [Python](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7.6/) in your PATH (**not 3**, I have 2.7)
3. (Optional: Make sure you have Perl in your PATH (I used ActivePerl 5.14.2 64-bit))
4. Get [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) and put it in your PATH
5. Go to the [LLVM downloads page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) and download the LLVM 3.0 source code along with the Clang source code. Don't get the code from the SVN, it doesn't work with the MinGW headers.
6. Extract the source codes; I had the llvm source in a folder named llvm-3.0.src on my desktop
7. Put the clang source directly in a folder called "clang" (it must be called this exactly or you will build llvm but clang won't get built) in the "tools" folder inside the llvm source folder, this should make your directories look like:

   - llvm source

     - autoconf folder
     - ...
     - tools folder

       - ...
       - clang folder

         - bindings folder
         - ...
         - Makefile file
         - ...
       - ...
     - ...
8. Make a folder named "build" in the same directory as the llvm source folder
9. Open a command line and cd into the build folder
10. Run the command `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..\llvm-3.0.src`

    - (the last argument is the relative path to the folder that has the llvm source in it (and the clang source in the tools/clang subdirectory))
    - This will do the equivalent of a "configure" command, and the makefiles and everything will be generated in the build folder
    - This will take a few minutes
11. Run the command `mingw32-make`

    - This will compile llvm and clang, and the clang executables will be generated in the build/bin folder
    - This will probably take a long time. (You can try to speed it up by adding parallel builds, `-j<number>` option) It might be good to close all other programs so that your computer can concentrate, and so they don't interfere with the lengthy compilation process, such as putting a lock on a folder that the compiler is writing to (it happened to me). I even turned off my antivirus and firewall software so that they wouldn't try to scan the generated files and get in the way.

Time for testing it out

1. Create a .cpp file in the build/bin folder (I will use hello.cpp). Use a standard library header to make sure the include paths and libraries are working. Start with a very simple program.

   (What I started with:

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       std::cout << "hi";
   }
   ```

   )
2. Run the command `clang hello.cpp -std=c++0x -I"C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++" -I"C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++\mingw32" -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../.. -L/mingw/lib -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt`

   (-L specifies a directory in which to search for libraries and -l specifies a library to link)
   (If you do not have MinGW installed to the same path as I did, you can find out the paths with the command "g++ somefile.cpp -v" to get g++ to spill its guts about what options it is using for the library paths and library files and everything else
   Search near the end of the output for the -L and -l options. Be aware of the .o file names that are interspersed with the -L's. Clang uses many of the same options as g++ so I literally copied and pasted that line from the output of g++)

   This should compile your program and produce a file named a.out
3. rename a.out to a.exe or whatever
4. Run the .exe
5. Your program should run.

Clang (3.0) still has some problems on Windows (I don't know if these problems are also on linux). For example, compiling a lambda (which clang doesn't support) with -std=c++0x will cause clang to crash and emit a diagnostic error.
(I was informed on the LLVM IRC that this is because clang implements parsing for lambdas but not semantic analysis, which is the phase in which it crashes (because they forgot to disable parsing lambdas for the 3.0 release), and they already know about this bug)

Also, the illustrious Mysticial kindly agreed to test this guide and made some observations during his testing:

1. Windows headers seem to work.
2. Currently only works for 32-bit.
3. 64-bit compiles fine, but won't assemble.
4. SSE probably is fine. ([Mysticial hasn't] tested a working SSE on 32-bit though.)

Comment: Clang does support lambdas now, though only in the SVN version. It always crashes when using lambdas, even on Mac OS X.

Comment: I managed to compile but for some sources, the compiler just hangs.

Comment: @Aftershock yeah, if you just want to use clang then you'll probably want to use rubenvb's prepackaged versions, they're more up to date than 3.0.

Comment: @daknøk In my testing lambda's have actually worked pretty well using  trunk clang on OS X. Some lambda's even work in the Xcode 4.3 version of clang, but crashes aren't uncommon there.

Comment: Will it work for the newer version of llvm currently 8.0.1 they released.? I tried the same way But it is giving the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303123/how-to-build-clang-with-mingw-on-winodws. please let me know any solution available for this error.

Answer (score 5):

Here is *what worked* in my environment, on Windows 8.1, overall similar to Seth's instruction, but with fresher tools.

1. I installed MinGW 64 into `C:/MinGW`, to be precise I've used [STL's distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).
2. I installed Python 3, just took their latest version.
3. I installed [CMake 3.0.2](http://www.cmake.org/download/)
4. I forked [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm) and [Clang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang) on Github and cloned them to my machine, placing Clang's repo into llvm\tools\clang folder (the structure is described [on the official page](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html), they just show examples with svn instead of git).
5. I created "build" folder next to "llvm" folder, and inside the "build" folder ran this command: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D"CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/MinGW/bin/make.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..\llvm`  (for some reason CMake couldn't find the "make" automatically)
6. Then I ran "make" to actually build. The build took a couple of hours.
7. After that in another folder I've created 1.cpp, which executes a lambda expression to print "hi":

> ```
> #include <iostream>
>
> int main() {
>     []{ std::cout << "hi"; }();
> }
> ```

8. I've also created a cmd file to compile the cpp. Alternatively you can just set the PATH variable properly via other means. Note that GCC vesrion in your MinGW package may be different. Also Clang has some builtin paths it tries, but they are tied to specific GCC versions, and mine was not among them, so I had to provide the include paths explicitly.

> ```
> set PATH=<path to the build folder from step 5>/bin;c:/mingw/bin;%PATH% 
> clang++ -std=c++11 1.cpp -o 1.exe -I"C:/MinGW/include"
> -I"C:/MinGW/include/c++/4.9.1" -I"C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.9.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32" -I"C:\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include"
> ```

9. Running that cmd compiled 1.cpp into 1.exe that printed "hi".

What *did not work*:

1. I've tried building the same llvm+clang sources without MinGW+GCC using the MSVC compiler from VS 2015 CTP. It built Clang successfully, the only difference is that you need to do that from the Developer CMD window, and you'd need to run  `cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ..\llvm` and then compile the solution in Visual Studio. However, that Clang failed to compile a sample cpp, it complained about "undeclared identifier 'char16_t'" and "__int128 is not supported on this target" within the MinGW standard library headers. If I use clang-cl and MS STL headers it complains about "throw x(y)" specifiers . Maybe I needed to provide some extra keys to the build, but I couldn't get it to work.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\include\xiosbase(293,4) :  error: cannot compile this throw expression yet _THROW_NCEE(failure, "ios_base::eofbit set"); 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\include\xstddef(56,30) :  note: expanded from macro '_THROW_NCEE'    #define _THROW_NCEE(x, y)    throw x(y)

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I did last time. Have you checked how well this all works with CygWin? I'm gonna need a Windows environment with clang next year. This time, I was thinking of using mostly CygWin, because of things like CygWin/X, etc.

Comment: @polemon, sorry, I don't have Cygwin installed, and I haven't tried using clang with it.

Comment: @polemon I just tried to do it. However, CMake cannot find the files in the tools subdirectory inside llvm, as a hidden "cygdrive/c/" is generated for the file paths for cmake--Cygwin somehow hijacked the file system. I used a binary from CMake' site. Using the cmake that came with Cygwin gave me "Could not create named generator MinGW Makefiles". I'm still trying to find a solution. Just a quick note, there is a 32 port in Cygwin, but if your programs tend to do number crunching stuff, the performance of executables from that is bad.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing , It is giving the error which I couldnt find any solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303123/how-to-build-clang-with-mingw-on-winodws

Answer (score 2):

Refer http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#buildWindows

I've used "Visual Studio 11 Win64" with cmake and its worked with the currently available VS Express for Desktop.

Also for lib I'm using MinGW-W **64** and for missing files SUA. http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.suacommunity.com/

For linking .o compiled by clang++ for use with the W **64** binaries, I use -m i386pep with ld linker again shipped within the W **64** deliverable.

Comment: Did you use VS express for Desktop? Is it not asking for atlbase.h file?

Answer (score 0):

I had numerous problems building LLVM and clang using VS and being a Unix user I prefer building sources from the command line.

Following the instructions from Seth Carnegie I built it from the SVN repository as opposed to the supplied packages, using LLVM v3.3 with MinGW v4.5.2.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, and noted for the future.

Comment: I tried all the option , It is throwing me error Which I cant find any solution. I am posting this comment here because atleast I will get the answer from any one who built it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303123/how-to-build-clang-with-mingw-on-winodws please have a look on this error.

Answer (score 0):

`clang` on `Windows` is NOT stand-alone, and it needs to be combined with another compiler (like `MingW` or `MSVC`).

The steps to do said combination are rather complicated, at least if you don't want to miss anything, hence the "build script" is worth an entire project:

https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw

I have tested `llvm-mingw` project's version 20220906 (at time of writting, latest version), and it combines `clang 15.0.0` with `MingW` seamlessly.

> See pre-built binary releases:
> https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases
>
> Or try what worked for me:
> https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases/download/20220906/llvm-mingw-20220906-msvcrt-i686.zip