# Clang with -faddress-sanitizer on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, clang, valgrind

My intent is to use `Clang` as a replacement for `Valgrind` on Windows to find buffer overflows, dynamic memory misuse etc. in C/C++ programs that I've written. I have successfully built Clang following the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427356/how-to-compile-clang-on-windows).

I attempted to compile a simple C program with the -faddress-sanitizer option (as specified [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)) and the following the error is thrown -

```
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-faddress-sanitizer'
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.0/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-      c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC)
clang: error: assembler (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is clang (as I understand it) invoking GCC? Of course GCC does not support the -faddress-sanitizer option.

I am really excited at the possibility of using this as I've been trying to find a good (free) substitute for Valgrind for a while. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AddressSanitizer works much better on Windows these days (but it's still a bit of a work-in-progress). There's some documentation at https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerWindowsPort

Comment: I've fixed the link now to point to https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerWindowsPort

Answer (score 8):

Googling brought me to [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#platforms).

To quote,

> AddressSanitizer is supported on
>
> - Linux x86_64 (tested on Ubuntu 10.04).
> - MacOS 10.6 and 10.7 (i386/x86_64).
>
> Support for Linux i386/ARM is in progress (it may work, but is not guaranteed too).

---

On the topic of replacement, have you looked at [Dr. Memory](http://www.drmemory.org/)?

Comment: Thanks but it appears that Address Sanitizer should work on Windows according to [this](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/WindowsPort).

I did give Dr. Memory a try recently, it didn't catch buffer overflows but it did catch uninitialized reads in memory. The single most important feature I'm after is detection of buffer overflow.

Comment: Did you follow those instructions fully?

Comment: I attempted to but stopped short because the instructions use MSVC to compile address sanitizer. I am using MinGW32.

Comment: I will accept your answer until I can get it working myself. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I wish you luck. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx) is a list of flags for `cl` so you can perhaps port whatever needs to be made to use MinGW.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking at but I ran into a header file problem (intrin.h) that's only available on MSVC. It might require more hacking that I thought to get it compile using MinGW. But definitely worth the trouble if I can get it working.

Comment: There appears to be a GCC-compatible port [here](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fidAD4BE239980B0FA1EC05A674929EFE86553B016E.aspx).

Comment: Gee, thanks! That's really helpful, I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: No problem; I'm only hoping I can provide as much help as possible.

Comment: Dr. Memory page says that it can't handle 64-bit applications, unfortunately.