# Does Cygwin have any "address sanitizer" tool at all (NOT necessarily "libasan")?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, address-sanitizer

I like to program using gcc and g++ on Cygwin on Windows 10. But although man gcc presents the "-fsanitize=address" option, it doesn't seem to actually work. I get "cannot find -lasan". And searching Cygwin's package repository for "lasan", "libasan", "asan" or "sanit" returns nothing relevant. Is "Address Sanitizer", then, a Linux-only thing, with no equivalent in Cygwin? And if it is, what other tools are available on Cygwin for achieving the same or similar goals?

Comment: libasan is not supported on\for windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806469/clang-with-faddress-sanitizer-on-windows

Comment: "Cygwin on Windows 10" Might I ask why you don't just use WSL?

Comment: @Swordfish Might I ask why you use WSL?

Comment: I don't. But I do not use cygwin either. Its just that gccs address sanitizer should be working under WSL.