# Problems installing Clang in windows

Tags: c++, windows, installation, clang, llvm-clang

I've been trying to install clang in virtual machine with windows xp, first I try with the Pre-Built Binaries of clang for Windows from this page: [LLVM Download](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) and I was getting this error:

```
Failed to find MSBuild toolset directory
```

So, I try to compile clang following the step explain in this question: [Compiling Clang in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427356/how-to-compile-clang-on-windows), but I'm also getting an error:

```
In file included from C:\llvm-3.7.0.src\lib\Support\DynamicLibrary.cpp:40:0:
C:\llvm-3.7.0.src\lib\Support\Windows/DynamicLibrary.inc:34:56: error: 'PENUMLOA
DED_MODULES_CALLBACK64' has not been declared
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *fpEnumerateLoadedModules)(HANDLE,PENUMLOADED_MODULES_CALL
BACK64,PVOID);
                                                    ^
C:\llvm-3.7.0.src\lib\Support\Windows/DynamicLibrary.inc: In static member funct
ion 'static llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::getPermanentLib
rary(const char*, std::string*)':
C:\llvm-3.7.0.src\lib\Support\Windows/DynamicLibrary.inc:70:65: error:  invalid conversion from 'BOOL (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(PSTR, DWORD64, ULONG, PVOID) {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)(char*, long long unsigned int, long
unsigned int, void*)}' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
 fEnumerateLoadedModules(GetCurrentProcess(), ELM_Callback, 0);
                                                             ^
lib\Support\CMakeFiles\LLVMSupport.dir\build.make:1912: recipe for  target 'lib/S
upport/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/DynamicLibrary.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/DynamicLibrary.cpp.
obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:200: recipe for target 'lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.
dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:148: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I really don't know what to do at this point or what am I doing wrong, so any help in this topic will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can see "[IoT Development with PlatformIO](http://electronicsworkbench.io/blog/platformio)", which showcases the same error message.

[image: http://electronicsworkbench.io/user/pages/02.blog/platformio/clang-install-error.jpg]

> Checking the installed files, I found an `install.bat` in the `C:\Program Files\LLVM\tools\msbuild` directory.
>   It searches for the MSBuild toolset directory in places like "`%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\%PLATFORM%\PlatformToolsets`", and copies some files from LLVM to the MSBuild directory if it finds them.
>   Otherwise the above error is thrown.
>   This confirmed that the error is not relevant for this environment, we can just ignore it.

In your case, you might not be able to ignore it, so double-check the content/existence of that folder.