# How to use and configure clang-tidy on windows?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use clang-tidy code analysis so I can check for CppCoreGuidelines. I downloaded LLVM 7.0.0 pre-built binary for Win 7 64 bits. I'm able to successfully compile with clang, I did a basic example compiling this  code, I named the source test.cpp:

```
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I ran this in the terminal:

```
clang test.cpp
```

I got this output when compiling:

```
test-c4b051.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __std_terminate imported in function "int `public: static unsigned __int64 __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::length(char const * const)'::`1'::dtor$2" (?dtor$2@?0??length@?$char_traits@D@std@@SA_KQEBD@Z@4HA)
test-c4b051.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _CxxThrowException imported in function "public: void __cdecl std::ios_base::clear(int,bool)" (?clear@ios_base@std@@QEAAXH_N@Z)
```

But it worked fine printing "Hello World" and everything goes fine until here, but when I want to run clang-tidy I get the following output when I run this, I took the reference from here [Extra Clang Tools 8 documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/):

```
clang-tidy test.cpp -checks=-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-cplusplus*



Error while trying to load a compilation database:
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "test.cpp"
No compilation database found in C:\Users\uidr8361\Desktop\C++ or any parent directory
fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: no such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: no such file or directory
Running without flags.
```

I read this thread but this seems to apply for clang compilation and I don't know if this also applies for clang extra tools, clang-tidy in particular:
[How to compile Clang on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427356/how-to-compile-clang-on-windows)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just put -- (minus minus) on the command line at the end

```
clang-tidy -checks=-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-cplusplus* test.cpp --
```

You would normally put your cl,gcc,clang arguments afterwards

```
clang-tidy -checks=-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-cplusplus* test.cpp -- -DDEBUG -I./include
```

Comment: I had to add quotes for the clang analyzer parameters:                          
```clang-tidy -checks="-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-cplusplus*" main.cpp```