# How to build clang with MINGW on winodws?

Tags: c++, windows, clang, mingw, llvm-clang

I am trying to build clang from the source code using MINGW on Windows 8.

I downloaded the clang from the source and other necessary tools from the official page of llvm

clang-llvm source code : `git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git`

`cmake and ninja` I downloaded just like in the below page

`http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html`

I m running on terminal and giving the following commands

```
cmake -GNinja -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /path/to/llvm
```

So cmake output some files in the folder where it is running

But In the next step If I give ninja

after 5 step it is giving following error

```
In file included from ../lib/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.cpp:14:0:
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h: In instantiation of 'void llvm::itanium_demangle::FloatLiteralImpl<Float>::printLeft(llvm::itanium_demangle::OutputStream&) const [with Float = long double]':
../lib/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.cpp:587:1:   required from here
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h:2177:23: warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]
       int n = snprintf(num, sizeof(num), FloatData<Float>::spec, value);
                       ^
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h:2177:23: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
       int n = snprintf(num, sizeof(num), FloatData<Float>::spec, value);
               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h: In instantiation of 'void llvm::itanium_demangle::FloatLiteralImpl<Float>::printLeft(llvm::itanium_demangle::OutputStream&) const [with Float = double]':
../lib/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.cpp:587:1:   required from here
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h:2177:23: warning: unknown conversion type character 'a' in format [-Wformat=]
       int n = snprintf(num, sizeof(num), FloatData<Float>::spec, value);
                       ^
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h:2177:23: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
       int n = snprintf(num, sizeof(num), FloatData<Float>::spec, value);
               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h: In instantiation of 'void llvm::itanium_demangle::FloatLiteralImpl<Float>::printLeft(llvm::itanium_demangle::OutputStream&) const [with Float = float]':
../lib/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.cpp:587:1:   required from here
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h:2177:23: warning: unknown conversion type character 'a' in format [-Wformat=]
       int n = snprintf(num, sizeof(num), FloatData<Float>::spec, value);
                       ^
../include/llvm/Demangle/ItaniumDemangle.h:2177:23: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
       int n = snprintf(num, sizeof(num), FloatData<Float>::spec, value);
               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[22/4328] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.obj
FAILED: lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe  -DGTEST_HAS_RTTI=0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Ilib/Support -I../lib/Support -Iinclude -I../include -std=c++11 -Werror=date-time -std=gnu++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment  -O2 -DNDEBUG    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -MD -MT lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.obj -MF lib\Support\CMakeFiles\LLVMSupport.dir\Chrono.cpp.obj.d -o lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.obj -c ../lib/Support/Chrono.cpp
../lib/Support/Chrono.cpp: In function 'tm llvm::getStructTM(llvm::sys::TimePoint<>)':
../lib/Support/Chrono.cpp:35:15: error: '::localtime_s' has not been declared
   int Error = ::localtime_s(&Storage, &OurTime);
               ^~
[25/4328] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CodeGenCoverage.cpp.obj
FAILED: lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CodeGenCoverage.cpp.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe  -DGTEST_HAS_RTTI=0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Ilib/Support -I../lib/Support -Iinclude -I../include -std=c++11 -Werror=date-time -std=gnu++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment  -O2 -DNDEBUG    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -MD -MT lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CodeGenCoverage.cpp.obj -MF lib\Support\CMakeFiles\LLVMSupport.dir\CodeGenCoverage.cpp.obj.d -o lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CodeGenCoverage.cpp.obj -c ../lib/Support/CodeGenCoverage.cpp
In file included from ../lib/Support/CodeGenCoverage.cpp:18:0:
../include/llvm/Support/Mutex.h:29:12: error: 'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
       std::recursive_mutex impl;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../include/llvm/Support/Mutex.h: In member function 'bool llvm::sys::SmartMutex<mt_only>::lock()':
../include/llvm/Support/Mutex.h:35:11: error: 'impl' was not declared in this scope
           impl.lock();
           ^~~~
../include/llvm/Support/Mutex.h: In member function 'bool llvm::sys::SmartMutex<mt_only>::unlock()':
../include/llvm/Support/Mutex.h:48:11: error: 'impl' was not declared in this scope
           impl.unlock();
           ^~~~
../include/llvm/Support/Mutex.h: In member function 'bool llvm::sys::SmartMutex<mt_only>::try_lock()':
../include/llvm/Support/Mutex.h:62:18: error: 'impl' was not declared in this scope
           return impl.try_lock();
                  ^~~~
[26/4328] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cpp.obj
FAILED: lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cpp.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe  -DGTEST_HAS_RTTI=0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Ilib/Support -I../lib/Support -Iinclude -I../include -std=c++11 -Werror=date-time -std=gnu++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment  -O2 -DNDEBUG    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -MD -MT lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cpp.obj -MF lib\Support\CMakeFiles\LLVMSupport.dir\CachePruning.cpp.obj.d -o lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cpp.obj -c ../lib/Support/CachePruning.cpp
In file included from ../lib/Support/CachePruning.cpp:16:0:
../include/llvm/Support/Errc.h:65:23: error: 'not_supported' is not a member of 'std::errc'
   not_supported = int(std::errc::not_supported),
                       ^~~
[27/4328] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APFloat.cpp.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Why clang is dependent in Windows.?
What is the wrong thing I am doing When building clang on windows.?

Please let me know if there is any solution .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probem. I just used chocolatey to install clang.
https://chocolatey.org/
After you install this, open windows power shell as administrator, and type this command:
`choco install llvm`.
This should install the compiler.